# Problem when I try to upload a video preview for iTunes connect

Tags: video, app-store-connect, preview

I used a lot of programs to convert and resize to apple format video but I have this error any suggestion for resolve this?

[image: Itunes preview]

I used this ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -acodec copy -crf 12 -vf scale=1080:1920,setsar=1:1 output.mp4

But I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Does the input video have any audio?

Official specs are at https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev4e413fcb8

Specifically the video needs:

- Stereo Audio

Even if there is no audio channel, App Store Connect will give you an error.

Comment: Thanks I will check that, because my video doesn't have audio